# C++11: how to get C++14 templated map::find

Tags: c++, c++11

I was wondering whether it was possible to implement the same template map::find operator that will be available in C++14 (according to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) in C++11.

```
template< class K > iterator find( const K& x );
```

My specific issue is that my class receives a const char* that I then convert to a std::string to store it in a map's key. That's ok for an insert method (sooner or later I will have to create the string).
However when I look up an item in the map I do not want to convert the const char* to a string just to compare it to the keys. The string class already has a method to compare to a const char*.

```
std::map<std::string, int> map_;
//...
bool find(const char* value)
{
    // a temporary string will be created and passed to find in C++11
    // the const char* will be passed to the key comparer in C++14
    return map_.find(value) != map_.end();
    // in C++11 the above is equivalent to
    std::string temp(value);
    return map_.find(temp) != map_.end();
}
```

Is there a way to avoid the temporary string in C++11?

Comment: "will be available" You say that as though C++14 isn't something that shipped over a year ago.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to avoid the temporary string in C++11?

No. Your use case is exactly why they added this feature to C++14. Literally; this is the [exact motivating example in the proposal](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3657.htm).

Any alternative standard library solution, like using `lower_bound` or some other algorithm, will generally have worse performance problems than just allocating memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in charge of the container type and are willing to change it, and you don't mind treating your key-value pair as const (i.e., you have no intention of updating a value once an element is inserted), then [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/) can be used with an ordered_unique index in place of `std::map<>`:

```
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/indexed_by.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>

struct transparent_less
{
    using is_transparent = int;

    template<typename T, typename U>
    constexpr
    decltype(std::declval<T&&>() < std::declval<U&&>())
    operator ()(T&& lhs, U&& rhs) const
        noexcept(noexcept(std::declval<T&&>() < std::declval<U&&>()))
    {
        return std::forward<T>(lhs) < std::forward<U>(rhs);
    }
};

namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;

template<typename K, typename V>
using transparent_map = bmi::multi_index_container<
    std::pair<K, V>,
    bmi::indexed_by<
        bmi::ordered_unique<
            bmi::member<std::pair<K, V>, K, &std::pair<K, V>::first>,
            transparent_less
        >
    >
>;

int main()
{
    transparent_map<std::string, int> map;
    map.emplace("foo", 1);
    map.emplace("bar", 2);
    std::cout << map.find("foo")->second << '\n'; // no std::string constructed
}
```

<kbd>**[Online Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64ff4680cab8eb07)**</kbd>

Aside from not being able to mutate a value, and the absence of `operator[]`, this should provide the same interface as `std::map<>`.

Comment: The immutability of the value part can be easily overcomed by using a suitable `mutable_pair` as shown at http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/techniques.html#emulate_assoc_containers

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: "No."

Long answer:
No, because you don't have access to `std::map` internals (of course you can code your own `map`). The comparator for your `std::map<std::string, int>` is `bool operator()(const std::string & lhs, const std::string & rhs) const`. This comparator uses `std::string`.

One possibility could be to use comparator like `bool operator()(const char * lhs, const std::string & rhs) const`. I think this is what you mean.

Digging into `std::map` implementation (xutility) in Visual Studio 2012 - the comparing is done in functions that look like this

```
template<class _Pr, class _Ty1, class _Ty2> inline
    bool _Debug_lt_pred(_Pr _Pred,
        const _Ty1& _Left, _Ty2& _Right,
        _Dbfile_t _File, _Dbline_t _Line)
    {   // test if _Pred(_Left, _Right) and _Pred is strict weak ordering
    if (!_Pred(_Left, _Right))
        return (false);
    else if (_Pred(_Right, _Left))
        _DEBUG_ERROR2("invalid operator<", _File, _Line);
    return (true);
    }
```

The `_Pred` is your comparision function. You can see this function is used with `_Pred(_Left, _Right)` and `_Pred(_Right, _Left)`. That's why `bool operator()(const char * lhs, const std::string & rhs) const` won't help. It's not symmetric.

Comment: "*One possibility could be to use comparator like `bool operator()(const char * lhs, const std::string & rhs) const`.*" But `std::map<>::find` still takes a `std::map<>::key_type const&` parameter, so using a different comparator doesn't avoid the allocation, even if you addressed the symmetry issue.

Comment: @ildjarn That's true. My reasoning is that it's not possible within current implementation. If there are more reasons, it's still not possible.

Comment: The operator's declared signature is not the problem because a function object containing multiple overloads of said operator could be used – or a template (in fact, this is part of the solution in C++14). The real problem is first what ildjarn refers to: `find()` (as well as `lower_bound` and `upper_bound`) itself requires a `const key_type&`, and second, that the public API is not expressive enough to solve this problem from user code.